# Compiling coffeescript with contracts in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I recently stumbled across a very cool dialect of coffeescript called [contracts.coffee](http://disnetdev.com/contracts.coffee/). I want to use it in my rails project, but I'm unsure how I can modify the compilation options of `coffee-rails`. In order to compile the contracts I need to run:

```
coffee -c --contracts script.coffee
```

Is the best option here to build my own gem? Or is there someway to customize the compilation parameters in the `coffee-rails` gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a **[gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/contracts.coffee-source)** for that. So just add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem "contracts.coffee-source", "~> 0.3.1"
```

Comment: Funny, I could not find this gem for the life of me. Thanks